# "Another version of Outlook is currently running. Close it and try again."

Tags: outlook-2010, exchange-2013

Our organization is running Exchange 2013 (upgraded a couple of months ago from 2007) and Office 2010. We have about 50 or so end users and over the past few weeks users have begun receiving the above-referenced message (in title) when they first start up Outlook. They are able to click Ok and Outlook will function normally. I have verified that there is not another instance of Outlook running on the client machines and I have also attempted to repair the Office installation without success. Also, strangely, I have not received the message yet.

Is anyone familiar with this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I've seen this - your clients may be also running OCS at login, or some other software that connects to the same MAPI profile; maybe some AV software, or other Outlook addon that starts up before Outlook itself.

That's my guess. You could run ProcMon from Sysinternals and see what's opening the OST/PST for the user's MAPI profile before Outlook does.

Run Procmon as soon as you login, with a filter for Path contains .OST (or .PST, depending on how you setup your clients.) See what processes, if any, have a handle open to the user's OST file. Seeing an open handle on the OST file is, IME, a decent proxy for having a MAPI connection.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I used ProcMon to do a scan while a user starts Outlook and receives the error message. Can you help me narrow down what filtering I need to do? Thanks (newb with procmon)

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: No OST or PST being found. After checking for the location of the datafile for my Outlook profile, it just shows as "Online." No PST or OST files in my user directory.